# Less than 100% branch coverage unit testing. How to fix that?

Tags: java, fibonacci

I have a memoized recursive function to calculate fibonacci numbers. I have test cases for this function. Basically it sends in a position and if there already is a number at that position, just return it and if there is not, calculate it. I ran my code through the debugger and realised that:

```
if (dictionary[position] != null){
    result = dictionary[position];
  }
```

is never hit. The full code below. For example, if you have calculatefib(4), that will ask for `fib(3)` which will ask for `fib(2)` which will ask for `fib(1)` which will ask for `fib(0)` and when the stack starts to close up, the values are never saved. so for example `fib(2)` or rather `dictionary(2)` is always null. Its confusing cause in the debugger it shows the values are calculated but when the stack starts to close up, they are null again. How do i refactor the code so the lines are always hit.

```
public BigInteger calculateFib(int position) {

final BigInteger[] dictionary = new BigInteger[100000];

BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;

if (position < 2) {
  return result;
}
else {
  if (dictionary[position] != null){
    result = dictionary[position];
  }
  else {
    result = calculateFib(position - 1).add(calculateFib(position - 2));
    dictionary[position] = result;
  }
  return result
```

Comment: You should declare your memo storage *outside* your method, as it has to remember things across method calls. Right now you're createing a new "memo" store `dictionary` for every method call so you're never remembering anything. Take this outside of your method to the class instance: `final BigInteger[] dictionary = new BigInteger[100000];`

Comment: Better yet, pass it along as an argument. And use a list.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I moved it and i am still getting a 75% on branch coverage

Comment: it still has a problem with this line: if (dictionary[position] != null). It says the hits are 26, true hits: 1, false hits: 1 and unknown outcomes: 24

Comment: @shmosel with the way the project is structured, i cant.

Comment: @shmosel for memoization, I typically use a map, unless the range of "keys" is sufficiently restricted that you can use something smart - because it's the easiest to look up and it's sparse. Passing it as an argument - don't see what that would be "better". I guess it depends on the usecase. Java has instances to store state so it doesn't need to get passed to every method call, but if you go for a more functional approach it may be more consistent to use arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `calculateFib()` this line:

```
final BigInteger[] dictionary = new BigInteger[100000];
```

creates a temporary instance of the array `dictionary[]`  
As soon as `calculateFib()` is finished, `dictionary[]` is destroyed.  
If you want to store the values in it and reuse it then you have to declare it at the class level outside `calculateFib()`.  
**Edit**, this is my approach to your logic:

```
final BigInteger[] dictionary = new BigInteger[100000];

public BigInteger calculateFib(int position) {
    if (position < 0)
        return BigInteger.ZERO;

    BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;


    if (dictionary[position] != null) {
        result = dictionary[position];
    } else if (position < 2) {
        dictionary[position] = result;
    } else {
        result = calculateFib(position - 1).add(calculateFib(position - 2));
        dictionary[position] = result;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: i just did but i still have 75% branch coverage. it still has a problem with this line: if (dictionary[position] != null). It says the hits are 26, true hits: 1, false hits: 1 and unknown outcomes: 24

Comment: @Devee I did some changes to your code because for example by your code the first 2 positions in the dictionary would always be null.

Comment: i get an array out of bounds exception. You see, one of my test cases is for where position = -2. When that is the case, it should return 1. With your code, once the compiler hits : if (dictionary[position] != null) , it gives an arrayoutofbounds exception.

Comment: *one of my test cases is for where position = -2* why?!!! Then one more condition is needed `if (position < 0) {   }`

Comment: I updated the code with the case where `position < 0 `

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your memo storage outside your method, as it has to remember things across method calls. Right now you're creating a new "memo" store dictionary for every method call so you're never remembering anything.

Take this outside of your method to the class instance:

```
final BigInteger[] dictionary = new BigInteger[100000];
```

Like

```
class MyClass {
    final BigInteger[] dictionary = new BigInteger[100000];

    public BigInteger calculateFib(int position) {      
        BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;

        if (position < 2) {
          return result;
        }
        else {
          if (dictionary[position] != null){
            result = dictionary[position];
          }
          else {
            result = calculateFib(position - 1).add(calculateFib(position - 2));
            dictionary[position] = result;
          }
          return result
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i just did but i still have 75% branch coverage. it still has a problem with this line: if (dictionary[position] != null). It says the hits are 26, true hits: 1, false hits: 1 and unknown outcomes: 24

Comment: which is weird even though now it hits that line.

Comment: "unknown outcomes: 24 " - that looks like a limitation in your branch coverage analysis tool

Answer (score 0):

It is not going to `memoize`  results the way you expect.
Every-time method is called you initialise a new dictionary which dies when the method is finished.

You need to pull the dictionary variable and initialise it out side of your method.

```
final BigInteger[] dictionary = new BigInteger[100000];
```

Comment: i just did but i still have 75% branch coverage. it still has a problem with this line: if (dictionary[position] != null). It says the hits are 26, true hits: 1, false hits: 1 and unknown outcomes: 24

Answer (score 0):

**Your code shows 100% coverage** if you move `dictionary` outside the method.

Here's a picture to prove it:

[image]

*However*, if I generate a "coverage report" it shows a 75% method coverage:

[image]

This report is obviously incorrect, since it shows every single method and line being hit, and it shows 100% method coverage in the IDE, so I'd say **the coverage tool is at fault here**. You may want to report a bug.